# Tox virtualenv confusion

Tags: python, tox

Just starting out using tox for testing a library with Python 2.7 and 3.4.   After using the following `tox.ini` file I had two questions:

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27,py3}
sitepackages = True

[testenv]
deps= -rrequirements.txt
commands = nosetests -w tests/ --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-package=pyppa --with-xunit --xunit-file={toxinidir}/build/ppa-python-sdk_{envname}_unit_tests.xml
coverage xml -o {toxinidir}/build/{envname}_coverage.xml
```

After running `tox` I had the following questions:

1. The project depends on `numpy` and `scipy` which are both installed in my global environment, I thought that using `sitepackages = True` in the `tox.ini` file would prevent tox from installing these in the virutalenvironment and force it to use those in the global environment but tox installed the latest versions in the `.tox/` virtual environments for both 2.7 and 3.  Am I misunderstanding the `sitepackages` directive?
2. Looking underneath the `.tox/` directory at the virtual environment directories I see the following (abbreviated) structure:

.

```
  .tox/
    py27/
      include/
        python2.7/
      lib
        python2.7/
      ...
    py3/
      include/
        python2.7/
      lib
        python2.7/
      ...
```

I assure you that this is not a typo.  There are directories named `python2.7` under the py3 virtual environment `include` and `lib` sub-directories and these are the only sub-directories in `include` and `lib`.   Everything seems to work but I'm just curious as to why these directories are named this way.  Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [`sitepackages`](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#confval-sitepackages=True|False) isn't a global Tox setting. It's an environment setting, so put it under `[testenv]`.

2) `py3` is not [a predefined variant](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-v2.html#default-settings-related-to-environments-names-variants). Use `py34` instead.